# Looking for the name of telescopic rod piece

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am looking for the name of a mechanical piece.
Here is the description:

The piece would be a telescopic rod of about 1 cm in diameter and 30 cm in height that would constantly try to extend vertically, and a weak resistance such as a when a finger presses a button would allow it to retract.

Does anyone know the name of this kind of piece?

Comment: spring loaded pogo stick

Answer (score 2):

Although the spring loading aspect and the finger retraction aspect aren't certain, you may be describing an [expandable baton](https://bestsurvival.org/best-expandable-baton/). The sized described in the linked site range from 12" (30cm) to 26" (65 cm) of varying diameters.

I found the linked site by searching for spring loaded telescoping rod, which returned a substantial number of inaccurate results.

One other return was for an [expandable baton](https://www.tbotech.com/telescopicbaton.htm) directed at self-defense, in a manner similar to the first link. Photo below from this linked site:

[image: telescoping baton]

Comment: What materials are used in the manufacture of these pieces? Is CFRP used everywhere or only in limited areas?

Comment: @dtn please do not post irrelevant questions in comments ... post your own question instead, [ask here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

This component is also known as a *gas cylinder* or *gas lift*. They are used to help open liftgates and rear windows on cars and minivans.